# KnockoutJS: Stop a particular property from setting dirty flag

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

With some help from StackOverflow community I was able to get my dirty flag implementation to work, based on this example: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html

It does exactly what I want, except for a single use case that I don't know how to solve.

Basically I have a select menu that gets automatically populated from the database. This select menu also has an option to make an Ajax call to my back end and have the list of options refreshed, database updated and return the `result`. This is where things get hairy for me.

First method works fine, however, it has to re-index and re-apply my entire `viewModel` and takes about 2-3 seconds, running on a local machine with 16gigs of ram and SSD.

```
jsondata.component.available_tags = result.available_tags;
ko.mapping.fromJS(jsondata, viewModel);
```

Second method also works, and pretty much instantaneous, however, it sets of `isDirty()` flag, which I would like to avoid, because this data is already coming from the database and I wont need to save it. I can not use `isDirty.reset()` method either, because if `isDirty` was set by something else before I clicked an menu option to update `available_tags`, it will reset that too. Which I would also like to avoid.

```
viewModel().component.available_tags(result.available_tags);
```

My question is: With the first method, can I force UI refresh with `ko.mapping.fromJS()` on a particular element and not entire dataset? Or, with a second method, can I avoid setting `isDirty` flag set when `available_tags` are updated? The twist is that I still need to keep `available_tags` as an observable, so the select menu is automatically generate/updated.

UPDATE: I was able to update mapping for that one single element with

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(result.available_tags, {}, viewModel().component.available_tags);
```

but that immediately set off `isDirty` flag... Argh

Comment: I think the key to the solution is 1) not to base your *entire view model* on one single `ko.mapping.fromJS()`, 2) making use of the mapping options, especially [the `key` property](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#uniquely_identifying_objects_using_keys) to avoid unnecessary rebuilds of things that did not actually change and 3) to split the view model into two sections: an "operational" part that has no connection to the dirty flag and a "user data" part that carries a dirty flag.

Comment: I had a huge perf hit when I first started integrating ko.mapping, and it turned out that I needed to very selectively choose which properties to turn into observables to save memory.

Comment: @Tomalak: While not exactly a solution it helped me alot. I stripped lots of fluff from my `viewModel`, and attached `isDirty()` flag directly to the only 2 properties I care about, instead of their parent. Please submit that as an answer, so I can make it as solved. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey, since you did all the work eventually (with "good" and "bad" code samples, too!) why don't you do the honors and write up a nice answer that lines out the problem and your solution? All I've done was to push you a little. I'll be around and vote you up (may give some more tips, too, if I see code that can be improved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Tomalak's suggestions, which I totally agree with, maybe the toJSON method can help you out in similar cases where you don't want to split the model. If your dirty flag implementation uses ko.toJSON as a hash function, as Ryan Niemeyer's does, you can give your model (on which the dirty flag is active) a toJSON method, where you do something like this:

```
function MyObjectConstructor() {
    this.someProperty = ko.observable();
    this.somePropertyNotUsedInDirtyFlag = ko.observable();
}
MyObjectConstructor.prototype.toJSON = function () {
    var result = ko.toJS(this);
    delete result.somePropertyNotUsedInDirtyFlag;
    return result;
};
```

Please be aware that this is also used to serialize the object in some other occassions, such as ajax calls. It's generally a handy function for removing computeds and such from your objects before using them in a different context.